# How to store a 3D array of floats in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

How should I store a 3D array of floats in C++? I only have 100x100x100 elements, so efficient storage isn't important.

In C I would have used `float arr[100][100][]`, but I suppose there is a more modern approach in C++. Since `std::array` has such a long type (`std::array<std::array<std::array<float>>>`), I feel like there is a better way.

What is the recommended solution?

Comment: Is it the long row that's bothering you? `using std::array` helps. I'd use a C-style array, std::array or std::vector. With a completely fixed size I'd use C-style, but that's subjective.

Comment: No, it just makes it seem like it wasn't meant for this purpose.

Comment: It was meant for that purpose, since [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) isn't that much different from the C-style.

Comment: @Anna Besides you missed to specify the size parameters for the `std::array` instantiations, what about using a `typedef` if it's bothering you _'writing the long type'_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multi_array from boost. It does what you need.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html